# How to calculate subgradients

Tags: drake

```
cost = np.maximum(x 0)
RuntimeError: You should not call `__bool__` / `__nonzero__` on `Formula`. If you are trying to make a map with `Variable`, `Expression`, or `Polynomial` as keys (and then access the map in Python), please use pydrake.common.containers.EqualToDict`.
```

I got the above error when trying to do: `Evaluate(cost.Jacobian(vars), dic)`

Are subgradients supported? How to do it?

EDIT:

```
Evaluate(cost_fnx.Jacobian(x_var), dic)
*** RuntimeError: The following environment does not have an entry for the variable x(0)
x(1) -> 2
x(0) -> 2
```

When I loop over the scalars of my vector x, and use symbolic.max, I get a runtime error - I assume because it's not supposed to work?

When I try the AutoDiff method, I get:

```
(Pdb) cost_fnx(InitializeAutoDiff(x_sample))
*** TypeError: 'pydrake.symbolic.Expression' object is not callable
```

My cost function is a very complicated function made of `prog.NewContinuousVariable` variables, not just the max. My guess is maybe I can use the AutoDiff max and combine it with the rest of my `NewContinuousVariable` cost function somehow?

Comment: When you write cost = np.maximum(x, 0), what is the type of x? Is it a list of double or a list of symbolic variables?

Comment: List of np object (Mathematical program variables)

Answer (score 1):

I assume `x` is a symbolic variable. Then instead of using `cost = np.maximum(x, 0)`, you can call

```
cost = pydrake.symbolic.max(x, 0)
```

This will create a proper symbolic expression.

BTW, I would recommend not to use symbolic evaluation in `cost` function. A better way is to define a function as below, and you can compute the gradient through using autodiffscalar (an implementation of automatic differentiation)

```py
def cost(x):
    if x.dtype == float:
        return np.maximum(x, 0)
    elif x.dtype == object:
        return x if x >= 0 else 0 * x

# Compute the gradient of cost at x = -2
Print(ExtractGradient(cost(InitializeAutoDiff([-2])))) # This prints 0

# Compute the gradient of cost at x=1
Print(ExtractGradient(cost(InitializeAutoDiff([1])))) # This prints 1
```

Comment: Hi, I want to calculate relu over an array. How do I do this?

Comment: The max only supports scalars. I suppose I could loop over the array using it, but seems slow - would be better if vectorized

Comment: Why is the autodiff method you proposed better? Does the symbolic way not support subgradients?

Comment: I tried some stuff and made an edit to the main post